# acts_as_followers and friendly_id gems not finding id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id, acts-as-follower

Im using the [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) gem and [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Iv set up acts_as_follower and everything is working as it should, I am able to follow `Profiles` as required. But now I have added the `friendly_id` gem to show profiles urls as `profile/myname` rather than `profile/1`.

But now the `acts_as_follower` gem doesn't work, it can't find the profile id to follow:

This is the set up what I'm trying now, but this still does not work.

```
  def follow
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    current_user.follow(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unfollow
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Before it was:

```
@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=
```

There params that are being passed are:

```
{"id"=>"gurmukh-singh"}
```

the id its now looking for is the friendly url `name`

Also the new friendly_id version requires i find profiles like this:

```
def set_story
  @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller you need to change it to

```
  def follow
    @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unfollow
    @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
    current_user.stop_following(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Then this should work

Comment: still getting this error `Couldn't find Profile without an ID` and the params being sent are `{"id"=>"gurmukh-singh"}`. The id should be something like `1` or something, not sure why the names being passed because its trying to find `(params[:profile_id])`

Comment: It's not one because friendly Id made it into a slug

Comment: its trying to find the `id` but the params its passing is the `slug`, but cant find it because there is not `id` which is stored as the `slugged` name

Comment: it works, but had to make a small change, iv edited the answer